# Comparing row data from the same table of 2 different database using SQL Developer

Tags: compare, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have 2 databases, identical in the tables and structure but contain almost identical data rows. Using SQL Developer (it is the only GUI I have available and unable to add any other software) I am trying to compare and identify which rows are contained in one database but not the other. They should contain the same data (this is reference data used elsewhere).

I am however unable to write a comparison to compare db1, schema1, table1, rows1 against db2, schema2, table2, rows2 to give a row delta result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to create a **database link** from e.g. DB1/schema1 to DB2/schema2.

Then it is a matter of your SQL skills and desires; a simple option would be - if you're connected to DB1/schema1 - to run

```
select * from table1
minus
select * from table2@database_link_name
```

That would return all rows that exist in your current DB1/schema1/table1, but don't exist in DB2/schema2/table2.